# Stretch and fill image in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using `bootstrap` carousal and having some problem with image height and width. Even though I define it in the `img` attribute it still displays as original resolution. Following is the code I am using:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/650x450/aaa&text=Item 3" height="300" width="300" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/aaa&text=Item 3" height="300" width="300" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/aaa&text=Item 3" height="300" width="300" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a1x1dnaa/) of that.

What should I do to fill the image in a certain height and width regardless of its original resolution?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `background-size: cover`, while still having hidden `<img>` element for SEO and semantic purposes. Single img url is used both times, so there's no additional loading, and [background-size is well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) (unlike `object-fit` which [lacks support](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) in IE, Edge and Android < 4.4.4).

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/matijamrkaic/ec33wonv/5/)

HTML change:

```js
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400);">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"/>
</div>
```

CSS change:

```
.carousel {
  /* any dimensions are fine, it can be responsive with max-width */
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
}

.carousel-inner {
  /* make sure your .items will get correct height */
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: can you specify how to make it responsive on your response please ?

Comment: @xavier This is the responsive way to display image (eventually use `contain` instead of `cover`). Responsiveness of the whole carousel is not part of the question, still it is hinted already that you can use `max-width` to make it adaptable in width.

Answer (score 8):

You can place height in css and add !important because bootstrap is overriding your height with auto , and object-fit:cover; will work like background size cover
[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzy2u51b/1/)

```
.carousel{
  width:300px;
}
.item img{
  object-fit:cover;
  height:300px !important;
  width:350px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That you have width in placeholder should not matter, put this in your css and it should work, If it works you can try remove !important.

```
 .carousel img {
        width:100% !important;
        min-width:100 !important;
        height: auto;
    }
```

.img-responsive in bootstrap will just set the width to 100%, So in the case that the image original proportions are less than carousel width it will not fill it out.

Comment: i tried that but the problem is that it will use actual width of the image itself and i dont want that. I want the carousal height and width to be 300x350 and no matter what height or width image it is but fill in that carousal only

Answer (score 2):

You're defining the size of your placeholders in the URL, not in the HTML attributes for the elements.

Also check out Bootstrap's .img-responsive class [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images).

**Update**

This has changed to `.img-fluid` in Bootstrap 4 Alpha and Beta

Comment: i think responsive image and defining height and width both doesnt work together. right

Answer (score 2):

Make your image take up 100% of the container size.
using  height:100% and width:100%.

Then restrict the size by setting values of the container to desired size.

```
.item{
  height:300px;
  width:350px;
}
.item img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The carousel will grow to fit whatever the parent is by default, which in your case is `.col-md-6` and `.col-sm-6`. If you want the carousel to be 300x300, style the carousel class/id or whatever to be the dimensions you want.

Then after that, bootstrap applies `height: auto;` to images in the carousel, which will override the `height` attribute you've specified in the HTML. 2 ways you can address that - either make the `height` (and for consistency sake, `width`, too) an inline `style` on the `img` tag if you want to keep it in the HTML, or apply the height to carousel images in your CSS file.

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.carousel, .carousel img {
  width: 300px;
}
.carousel img {
  height: 300px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This condensed the carousel to a thin column along the left edge of the browser window.  It works in that thin window but...

Comment: but it only works if I set `width: auto;` and `height:auto;`

Comment: @mLstudent33 I would encourage you to review your usage of the downvote button - https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down. The answer is to the original question, and the answer shouldn't be downvoted because it doesn't work for your particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

img tag using "object-fit: cover" property

```css
.carousel {
    height: 300px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}            

.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;                
}

.item img {
    object-fit: cover;
/*
    object-fit: fill;
    object-fit: none;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-fit: scale-down;
*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active" >
              <img src="http://placehold.it/650x450/aaa&text=Item 1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />            
            </div>

            <div class="item" >
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/aaa&text=Item 2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />            
            </div>

            <div class="item" >
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/aaa&text=Item 3" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />            
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

#### Codepen

[Editor](https://codepen.io/antelove/pen/QRZyLX)

[Full view](https://codepen.io/antelove/full/QRZyLX)

[Version of background .item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651515/apply-background-sizecover-to-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-slides/56354319#56354319)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the css of the file. This would restrict the height and width of the image and hence align it.

`.item img {
  max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 350px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

if it's okay for you to use simple javaScript, here is the updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/a1x1dnaa/2/

what i have done is, used the image as background and removed the `<img>` tag.

```
jQuery(function(){
  var items = $('.item');
  items.each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    img = item.find("img");
    img.each(function() {
        var thisImg = $(this);
        url = thisImg.attr('src');
        thisImg.parent().attr('style', 'background-image:url('+url+')');
        thisImg.remove();
    });
  });
});
```

then you can use some styles to make the image fill the div

```
.item {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  height: 200px; //you can use the height as you need 
}
```

this should work for you.

if you don't want to use javaScript, you can simply use the image as inline-style

```
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400)"></div>
```

and use the same CSS as above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this class in every image attribute

`class="img-responsive center-block"`

For example:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/aaa&text=Item 3" height="300" width="300" class="img-responsive center-block" />
```

2. Add this style

   ```
   .active img{
     width: 100%;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following styles:

```
.carousel-inner .item{
  width: 600px; /* Any width you want */
  height: 500px; /* Any width you want */
}
.carousel-inner .item img{
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

By setting `min-*` to the image attributes, we're making sure we have at least `100%` of both `width` and `height`.

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1x1dnaa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.item img{
min-width: 300px;
min-height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;}
.item{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

you try this css and little change in html. i used different image src for better clearification.

[here is updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitmonsterme/p1d0kt76/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the styling from the `img` tag:

```html
<!--from-->

<img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/aaa&text=Item 3" height="300" width="300" />
<!--to-->
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/aaa&text=Item 3"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
What worked for me is instead of using `img`, I used `div` and `background-image` for css

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <div class="carousel-img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner, .item {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-img {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/400x400');
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```