# How to make an image fit the carousel?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel with fixed size (for example, width=800px, height=450px). But I my images have different aspect ratio (16 : 9, 16:10, 1:1, etc) and the size, bigger than the size of my carousel. I am trying to make all the images reduce their size to fit my carousel.

Code of the carousel is:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="carousel-img" src="{{ last_post.image.url }}"
                             alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="carousel-img"
                             src="{{ second_last_post.image.url }}" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="carousel-img" src="{{ third_last_post.image.url }}"
                             alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner {
    height: 450px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

How can I resize images to fit the carousel?

Comment: Don't use a fixed size. There are many other questions on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152487/how-to-fully-fit-an-image-inside-carouselbootstrap, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685259/stretch-and-fill-image-in-bootstrap-carousel, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290701/maintain-image-aspect-ratio-in-carousel

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me. It will cover the entire div with your photo but this means that the photo will be zoomed-in as much as it needs to be to do that. So it must hide some (maybe critical) parts from the photo.

```
.carousel-img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Otherwise if you can use `object-fit: contain;` instead, to always display the entire photo into your measures.