# How to make image to fit a div inside component of react-slideshow-image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-slideshow-image

Im trying to make image to fit a div.
Im using `react-slideshow-image`.

**this is the CodSandbox :**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slide-imageshow-heightproblem-mforb?file=/src/App.js

```
return (
      <div className="App">
        <div style={{ width: "30%", height: "70px" }}>
          <Slide ref={this.slideRef} {...properties}>
            {slideImages.map((each, index) => (
                <img style={{ objectFit: 'contain', height : '100%'}} src={each} key={index} alt="sample" />
            ))}
          </Slide>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want the images to fit the div , so i can make the div **responsive**.
**if the div height is 70px, so the images inside it will also be the same height:70px**

I have tried this  [How to make an image fit the carousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381293/how-to-make-an-image-fit-the-carousel).

I have noticed that the `<Slide >` add divs so i looked at the [docs](https://react-slideshow-image.netlify.app/) and saw that you can add a property called `cssClass` that gets a `string`:

> Use this prop to add your custom css to the wrapper containing the sliders. Pass your css className as value for the cssClass prop

but it doesnt seems to work and i didnt found any examples for it.

Comment: What would help a lot would be if you add your rendered HTML.

Comment: Sorry, somehow the sandbox was deleted. here i have fixed it.

Comment: The problem comes from this line `<div style={{ width: "30%", height: "70px" }}>`. You need to remove `width:30%` and it will work okay.

Comment: Changing the line  `<div style={{ width: "30%", height: "70px" }}>`  doesn't help @Azu

Comment: I'm looking at your codesandbox code. If I remove `widht:30%` of the div directly in `div.App`, the images cover the whole width.

Comment: But the height is also the problem. i want the images to be, lets say `height: 70px` @Azu

Comment: I think the height comes from the Javascript. I tried to turn off the CSS properties but they appear again. Try to read the documentation of that slideshow library.

Comment: i have read the docs, and i got into the `cssClass` , and i think this is the only option for that but there are no examples for it

Comment: Does it say how to control height?

Comment: no, the document doesnt say how to handle height

Comment: I've found a div which can control the width and the height of the slider. It's `.react-slideshow-container`. You can give it width and height you wish:) Good luck!!!

Comment: it worked ! thank you !